# Letter appears in console output, but shouldn't. problem with Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage();

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to split code in classes. This code is sending to console text with `B` letter in start of line, but shouldn't.

Code:

```java
static ConsoleWrapper cw = new ConsoleWrapper();
cw.notify("using url:" + database.sql_url);
cw.notify("Plugin loaded!");
```

in ConsoleWrapper.java

```java
public class ConsoleWrapper {
    static String pluginName = App.pluginName;
    static ConsoleCommandSender console = Bukkit.getConsoleSender();

    public void notify(String msg) {
        // wrapper for console messages
        console.sendMessage(("§6[" + pluginName + "]" + msg));
    }
    
    public void alarm(String msg) {
        // wrapper for console messages
        console.sendMessage(("§c[" + pluginName + "]" + msg));
    }
}
```

but if `console.sendMessage(("§c[" + pluginName + "]" + msg));` executing in main class, letter `B` doesn't appeat in console.

> output with `cw.notify`

```
[12:01:07 INFO]: В[EggCounter] Plugin is starting first time, or restoring!
[12:01:08 INFO]: В[EggCounter]using url:jdbc:MYSQL://192.168.0.186:9889/easter_eggs
```

> output with  `console.sendMessage()`

```
[12:13:21 INFO]: [EggCounter]using url:jdbc:MYSQL://192.168.0.186:9889/easter_eggs
[12:13:21 INFO]: [EggCounter]Plugin loaded!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to write your own `§` because of possible encoding problem.

Prefer use `ChatColor` enum, like that:

```java
public class ConsoleWrapper {
    static String pluginName = App.pluginName;
    static ConsoleCommandSender console = Bukkit.getConsoleSender();

    public void notify(String msg) {
        // wrapper for console messages
        console.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[" + pluginName + "]" + msg);
    }
    
    public void alarm(String msg) {
        // wrapper for console messages
        console.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[" + pluginName + "]" + msg);
    }
}
```

You can find all color codes [here](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/color_list_pc.php).